# sql query to find all the updated column of a table

Tags: sql-server

I need a dynamic sql query that can get a column values of a table on the basis of any case/condition. I want to do that while update any record. And I need updated value of column and for that I am using Inserted and Deleted tables of SQL Server.

I made one query which is working fine with one column but I need a generic query that should work for all of the columns.

```
SELECT i.name 
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.id = d.id
WHERE d.name <> i.name
```

With the help of above query we can get "Name" column value if it's updated. But as it's specific to one column same thing I want for all the columns of a table in which there should be no need to define any column name it should be generic/dynamic query.

I am trying to achieve that by adding one more inner join with PIVOT of "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" for columns but I am not sure about it whether we can do that or not by this.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%table1%'
```

Comment: Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx about `columns_updated` function. I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that kind of information using just a query.  It sounds like you need to be running an update trigger.  In there you can code the criteria get your columns, etc.  From your question, it sounds like only one column can be updated, you are just not sure which one it will be.  If multiple columns are being updated, that complicates things, but not that much

There are several ways that you can get the data you need.  Off the top, I'd suggest some simple looping once you get the column names.

What has worked for me in similar scenarios is to do a simple query to INFORMAATION_SCHEMA.Columns and put the results in a table variable.  From there, iterate through the table variable to get one column name at a time and run a simple dynamic query to see if the value has changed.

Hope this helps.

:{)

Comment: #John, yes we can do that like you suggest. But in case of huge number of columns it will decrease the performance.That's why I am looking for a way that can do that in less time (like by join).